# Why do Outdated Page and Cache Removals self-happen in Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-index, seo-audit, google-cache

Take a look at the following screenshot I took from Google Webmaster Tools "Remove URLs" page:
[image: Self-happening Outdated Page and Cache Removals in Google Webmaster Tools]

None of these were performed by me or others who have access to GWT.

How do these removal requests happen without us doing any requests?

Why is that happening?

How to stop that or is there any point in stopping that?

Comment: I would think seriously about changing all of the passwords immediately just in case. Then carefully review who has an account and give them the new password you set for that account if it makes sense.

Comment: I've never seen this before. I'd change your password and revoke access to all other users temporarily. It's possible one of the other users credentials were compromised and they don't know it.

Comment: Thank you guys, but isn't it Google itself, who removes outdated cache and such?

Answer (score 1):

You need to click on the gear in the upper right hand corner of the page, and then click on the Users and Property Owners link. Delete any person who should not have access and change your password.

[image: Clear Gear in upper right corner then click users]

Answer (score 0):

People can still submit removal requests for your website using their own Google account. They will show in the Webmaster Tools, which is what you might be seeing?