# GWT Remove URLs Tab has requests for removal I didn't put

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search

I'm seeing in GWT a bunch of request of removal of pages, which weren't submitted from someone in my organization. I'm referring to the tab under Google Index->Remove URLs. Does it include any user-requested removals? How does someone submit such a request? It allows me to cancel a request (which I didn't submit in the first place) how does that make any sense?

Comment: Have you checked for any "rogue" verified users or "Users and Property Owners" within Google Search Console (formerly GWT)?

Comment: @w3d not sure where you mean. like here? https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/user-admin

Comment: Yes, and also under "Verification Details". No "out-of-date" verified users?

Comment: @w3d I look like the only verified owner. Also, seems the reasons on each entry are either "Outdated page removal" or "Outdated cache removal ", might that's a good clue? Also, in messages, I sometimes get a "Notice of removal from Google Search" but these doesn't seem linkedin to one another.

Comment: @Noam I have similar problem too: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/79061/why-do-outdated-page-and-cache-removals-self-happen-in-google-webmaster-tools